# how to save the last property when I use a transition in css

Tags: css

I currently have 3 divs. I do not know what is the best method so that when I click on an element this will keep the last property of the transition, but I need that this effect only happens for each element, one at a time.

```
.son{
 width:100px;
 background:#dcdcdc;
 margin:10px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Initially my elements have these properties:

```
.son:active{
 width:200px;
 background:yellow;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

but I want you to click twice, see the transition, but keep it in the last state. In the end these properties would remain. but I do not know how to do it so that they are saved, and I would like it when I click on another element, the last selected element returns to normality.

How can do it?

this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="son">text</div>
 <div class="son">text</div>
 <div class="son">text</div>    
</div>

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

.son{
 width:100px;
 background:#dcdcdc;
 margin:10px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.son:active{
 width:200px;
 background:yellow;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.son:focus{
 width:200px;
 background:yellow;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ndc6a587/

Answer (score 0):

:visited pseudo tag can help

```css
.container{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:center;
}

.son{
 width:100px;
 background:#dcdcdc;
 margin:10px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.son:active, .son:focus{
 width:200px;
 background:yellow;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.son a {display:block; text-decoration:none;color:#000;}

:target {
   width:200px;
   color:#000;
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="one" class="son"><a href="#one">text</a></div>
  <div id="two" class="son"><a href="#two">text</a></div>
  <div id="three" class="son"><a href="#three">text</a></div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It almost does what I need. But note that all can be yellow, I need the transition to apply only to the element that is clicked and saved for the element

Comment: By the way, I need to do it with divs, not with <a>.

Comment: @yavg check now

Comment: You are a genius !, but remember that my main problem is that the state is saved for each element, but it should only be saved for the element that is clicked, if another is clicked, the previous one should not save the state.

Comment: perfect.. is it the best way? is not posible only with css?

Comment: Personally, i would have chosen <a> so that I could use pseudo elements...

Comment: no JS now... but had to use <a> ... i would be thankful if you could share a better solution. I come to stack Overflow to learn all the time...